# SAS Safe Column Names (Updated)

Tags: sas, transpose

Is there a simple way in SAS to convert a string to a SAS-safe name that would be used as a column name?

ie.

```
Rob Penridge ---->  Rob_Penridge

$*@'Blah@*   ---->  ____Blah__
```

I'm using a `proc transpose` and then want to work with the renamed columns after the transpose.

**EDIT:** 
8 year follow-up... is there now a better way to do this? I feel like I saw a better method sometime back but I'm struggling to find any documentation/examples now that I need to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`proc transpose` will take those names without any modification, as long as you set `options validvarname=any;`

If you want to work with the columns afterwards, you can use the NLITERAL function to construct named literals that can be used to refer to them:

```
options validvarname=any;

/* Create dataset and transpose it */
data zz;
    var1 = "Rob Penridge";    
    var2 = 5;
    output;

    var1 = "$*@'Blah@*";
    var2 = 100;
    output;           
run;

proc transpose
    data = zz
    out  = zz_t;
    id     var1;
run;


/* Refer to the transposed columns in the dataset using NLITERAL */
data _null_;
    set zz;
    call symput(cats("name", _n_), nliteral(var1));
run;

data blah;
    set zz_t;
    &name1. = &name1. + 5;
    &name2. = &name2. + 200;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

May try perl regular expression function.
Since for column name, the first character should not be numerical, it's more complicated then.

```
data _null_;
name1 = "1$*@' Blah1@*";
name2 = prxchange("s/[^A-Za-z_]/_/",1,prxchange("s/[^A-Za-z_0-9]/_/",-1,name1));
put name2;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [VALIDVARNAME](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000279245.htm) System Option. It might allow you to accept non-valid SAS names.

Also the [NOTNAME](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002197357.htm) function could facilitate in helping find invalid characters.

Comment: +1 for suggesting NOTNAME.  Could have used this in a loop, but the regular expression approach is simpler and more concise.  I did use the documentation from this function to confirm the rules that SAS uses for valid names though so thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

How about using SAS's [`regular expression`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002296115.htm) functionality? For example:

```
data names;
 set name;
 name_cleaned = prxchange('s/[^a-z0-9 ]/_/i', -1, name);
run;
```

This will convert anything that isn't a letter, number, or space into a `_`. You can add other characters that you want to allow to the list after the `9`. Just be aware that some characters are "special" and must be preceded by a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `IDLABEL` statement in the transpose to add labels that match the original values. Then use the `VARLABEL` function to retrieve the labels and work with them that way.