# Replace dashes and spaces by underscores and make column names uppercase

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

In `sas eg`, for issues of compatibility, I need to copy a table renaming its columns to avoid spaces and dashes, and make the names uppercase.

Here are a sample of names from my table, in reality I have many more:

> - 'Call - Investments IN'
> - 'E-mail - Campaign'
> - 'E-mail - Investments OUT'
> - 'Letter - Campaign'

I want to get rid of the dashes and spaces and make the names upper case, these would be the columns of my output :

> - 'CALL_INVESTMENTS_IN'
> - 'E_MAIL_CAMPAIGN'
> - 'E_MAIL_INVESTMENTS_OUT'
> - 'LETTER_CAMPAIGN'

*Edit:*

*To be clear, my input is a table, and my output should be new table, and I don't want to type or copy paste individual column names, I want the operations to be done on ALL column names (I may have to use this on many columns on many tables that I receive from external sources).*

What sql query (or sas macro) should I use ?

Comment: Some alternatives are discussed here for dealing with unusually named columns in SAS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041632/sas-safe-column-names .  These aren't direct answers to your question but may be helpful for yourself or others arriving here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a RENAME statement or RENAME= dataset option.  You can easily generate the required `old=new` pairs into a macro variable if the list is not too long. To make sure you can change the case it is better to use the dataset option as there was just a question earlier showing that RENAME upper=UPPER does nothing in a DATA step as SAS sets the name's case based how it is first seen.

```
proc contents data=have noprint out=contents ; run;
proc sql noprint;
  select catx('=',nliteral(name),upcase(translate(trim(name),'__','- ')))
    into :rename separated by ' '
    from contents 
  ;
quit;
data want ;
  set have (rename=(&rename)) ;
run;
```

Comment: fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression and replace sub-strings of either a space character (either `\s` or ) or a dash `-` with a single underscore:

```
SELECT UPPER( REGEXP_REPLACE( table_name, '(\s|-)+', '_' ) )
FROM   your_list_of_tables
```

Comment: From `sag eg` it seems I cannot use these functions, but I can use `UPCASE` and `TRANSLATE` which seems to be the equivalents, however `'SELECT UPCASE( TRANSLATE( t1, '_', '(\s|-)+' ) ) FROM lib1.t1'` fails with `ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: t1.`

Answer (score 2):

First do a `proc contents` and output the column names to a table using `out` option. the columns names should be the column you want and varnum keeps the column position. then use `tranwrd` funtion to replace `-` by `_` and use `upcase` function to make all text uppercase -

`newcol = upcase(tranwrd(varname, '-', '_'))`

Use `proc sql` `into` clause on this table to create a list of var. Create new  table with new var names and set the older table.

`\\//`

Comment: This is moving in the right direction, I could create a table with : `PROC CONTENTS data= lib1.t1 OUT = temp_contents;run;` then could create a one column table with modified names with `PROC SQL;CREATE TABLE temp_contents2 AS SELECT upcase(tranwrd(name, '-', '_')) as newcol FROM WORK.temp_contents; QUIT;` . Now I need to assess these names to a copy of my original table, how do I do this ?

Comment: see the `temp_contents` table that you created has a column `varnum ` which tells the position of variable in source table. if you order your sql output by that column all the columns that you get in resulting dataset will be ordered in same way your source table has them. Then follow rest of  teh instructions and you will get there. :)

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

/*

How about having a macro to do it to any table you want it to :). Let me know if this works for you :)

Introduction: Renamer Macro

This macro will rename the columns of specified data set to comply with standard database column naming ethics.
It will do the following:

1) Replace all spaces with an underscore
2) Replace '+' sign with '_plus'
3) Replaces '-' with an underscore
4) Replaces any other special character with a blank ''
5) Saves the new data set in the target data and lib name specified

Syntax -

%Renamer_macro(source_lib,source_data,target_lib,target_data);

*/

```
options spool;
options mprint;
options mlogic;


%macro Renamer_macro(source_lib,source_data,target_lib,target_data);
%local names;
%Local sp_chars;

%Let sp_chars = ~’°-!()®@#$%^&©+=\/|[]}{]{?><‘—…... ;

Data &target_lib..&target_data.;
set &source_lib..&source_data.;
run;

proc sql noprint;

select catx('=',cats(cats(cats("'",name),"'"),"n"),
   cats(compress(translate(tranwrd(tranwrd(tranwrd(trim(name),"-","_")," 
         ","_"),"+","_plus"),"","&sp_chars"))))

   into :names separated by ' '
       from sashelp.vcolumn
       where libname= "%upcase(&source_lib)" and memname= "%upcase(&source_data)";

   %put &names;
/*and upcase(substr(name,1,2))='DX';*/

proc datasets lib= &target_lib.;
modify &target_data.;
rename &names;
quit;

%mend;
```