# SAS List of variables containing special characters

Tags: sas, special-characters

I am a novice for SAS programming and I am trying to create a list of old_variable names so I can work with them (subset, rename, spaces, etc.), however the variable names have funky characters (#, parenthesis, single quotes, numbers, you name it). Each variable is delimited-separated by ';' and the source file is in csv format. I need to do it for 44 different files and each file has about 199 variables.

So far, I have tried a macro where I create a list of the variables, however, the code fails when I try to use the macro &vars because of the special characters. I have checked SAS paper 005-2013, however I believe I am not really sure how to use the functions in my code.

Any insights or directions would be appreciated. Here is the code I tried so far:

1) Importing:

```
proc import datafile='file_oldname.csv'
 dbms=csv
 out= oldName
 replace;
 delimiter=',';
 getnames=yes;  
run;
```

2) Making my list of oldNames;
* A macro variable contanining the oldvariables names;
* Using Proc Contents and Proc SQL;

```
proc contents data=oldName out=listOldName;
run;

options VALIDMEMNAME=EXTEND;
proc sql noprint;
select distinct(name) into:vars separated by " " from listOldName;
quit;

%put &vars;
```

&vars contains the list of variables, however if I try to use it, it fails because of the special characters.

How can I wrap the &vars properly so that the variable names with special characters can be used? I want to further renamed them by new names.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041632/sas-safe-column-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your variable names contain special characters, they need to be referenced in `"name literal!"n` format.

Try:

```
options VALIDVARNAME=ANY;
proc sql noprint;
select distinct nliteral(name) 
  into:vars separated by ' ' 
  from listOldName;

%put &=var;
```

More info on name literals in [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm).

Edit - as kindly pointed out by @[Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4965549/tom), the nliteral function handily covers the conversion you require!  Documentation for that is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002270848.htm).

Comment: There is a function for that.  `nliteral()`

Comment: Allan, thank you so much for your input as well. All is good!!! You all are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

When `Proc IMPORT` runs it creates data sets with variable names that meet the `VALIDVARNAME` setting at import time.  Thus, one alternative, would be to set the option prior to IMPORT to ensure 'clean' variable names, and reset it afterwards.

```
%let setting = %sysfunc(getoption(VALIDVARNAME));

options validvarname=v7;
Proc IMPORT ... ;
  ...;
run;

options validvarname = &SETTING;
```

Example

```
filename have temp;

data _null_;
  file have;
  put 'Name,"Age","Date of Birth",School:First,Surprise!,-Feedback';
  put 'Abel,0,Yesterday,Eastern Acacdemy,Balloons!,None';
run;

options validvarname=any;
proc import file=have replace out=have_any dbms=csv;
  getnames=yes;
run;

options validvarname=v7;
proc import file=have replace out=have_v7 dbms=csv;
  getnames=yes;
run;

options validvarname=any;
```